# Get Yahoo user info after getting OAuth2 access token

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I've been trying to implement a "Login with Yahoo" option in my PHP site. I was able to do the first step which is to get the access token, as described here: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/

But I'm struggling to get the user data. To me their directions are not completely clear: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/get-user-inf/Get-User-Info-API.html

I've tried doing a call to https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo and passing the access token in a header like so: Authorization: Bearer <access_token> , I also tried passing the access token as a parameter in the url, and also as a post parameter.

Whatever i do i just get an empty string as a response. Has anyone dealt with Yahoo's user api endpoint?

This is my code (after getting access token):

```
$access_token = $res->access_token;
$token_type = $res->token_type;
$expires_in = $res->expires_in;
$refresh_token = $res->refresh_token;
$id_token = $res->id_token;

$host = urlencode("api.login.yahoo.com");

$userbody = "access_token=$access_token&Host=$host";

$userch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($userch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo/");
curl_setopt($userch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($userch, CURLINFO_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($userch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("GET /openid/v1/userinfo HTTP/1.1",
"Host: api.login.yahoo.com",
"Authorization: Bearer $access_token"));
curl_setopt($userch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($userch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$user = curl_exec($userch);

curl_close($userch);

var_dump($user);
```

** **EDIT** **

After using postman I got the right request, you're suppossed to pass id_token as a parameter in the url (they DON'T specify this in their guide), like so:

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo?id_token=<id_token>
```

And the only header needed (at least in postman) is:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

However, even though i get the user data in postman, i still get only an empty string in my php script. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Sending `GET /openid/v1/userinfo HTTP/1.1` and `Host: api.login.yahoo.com` as additional headers, likely makes little sense. The requested URL was specified via CURLOPT_URL already (although there you included an additional trailing slash, not sure whether the API might be sensitive to that.)

Comment: It might also make sense, to test using a tool like Postman first. Get the details of the request right first, then implement it in PHP afterwards. That way, at least you don’t have to guess whether the error is in the data/strcuture, or specific to the coding.

Comment: @CBroe Yes. It didn't make sense to me either but the way they show it in their guide looks like a header, and since they are not super clear about it i just tried it. Also, i was able to get the user data back in postman. However, even though i fixed the request in my script, i still get an empty string as a response. Any idea why?

Comment: That is more a general way to show what an HTTP request is supposed to look like, but that does not mean you have to set the actual request line or the host header yourself, cURL will do that, based on just the CURLOPT_URL. // Try and check if `curl_error` has anything to report.

Comment: @CBroe curl_error doesn't show anything. However I just checked the http code and get a 401, which is odd because i get a 200 with the same request in postman

Comment: @CBroe I solved it. I had accidentally removed the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER from the previous cURL, so i was just passing empty data to second cURL. It's working now

Answer (score 3):

After using postman I got the right request, you're suppossed to pass id_token as a parameter in the url (they DON'T specify this in their guide), like so:

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo?id_token=<id_token>
```

And the only header needed (at least in postman) is:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this situation occurs with old Yahoo apps. I had one created 4+ years ago.

Just create a new Yahoo app , and update the credentials.